# How to update sklearn in microsoft azure notebooks?

Tags: python, azure, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I am new at Machine Learning and I am looking at some of the Scikit-Learn documentation.
I use an account at Microsoft Azure https://notebooks.azure.com/.

Now I am trying to run the  code of this example:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_agglomerative_dendrogram.html .

I obtain the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-fc0d954d99ec> in <module>
 44 
 45 # setting distance_threshold=0 ensures we compute the full tree.
---> 46 model = AgglomerativeClustering(distance_threshold=0, n_clusters=None)
 47 
 48 model = model.fit(X)

   TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distance_threshold'
```

I have done a search and the problem is that I have sklearn '0.20.3' version and in order to run that code I need the 0.22 version.
I have been trying to update sklearn with

```
!pip install --update sklearn
```

and obtain this result:

```
Usage:   
pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --update
```

Searching the web it looks that there are some problem when trying to update sklearn in jupyter notebooks, but usually the answers are related to Anaconda Jupyter notebooks, not to Azure notebooks.

I will appreciate any hint to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

To update sklearn try using the below command:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

This works for me.

Comment: It didn't work . The errors shown are:

ERROR: azureml-train-automl 1.0.72 has requirement onnxmltools==1.4.1, but you'll have onnxmltools 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-train-automl 1.0.72 has requirement scikit-learn<=0.20.3,>=0.19.0, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.22.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-automl-core 1.0.72.1 has requirement onnxmltools==1.4.1, but you'll have onnxmltools 1.6.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: azureml-automl-core 1.0.72.1 has requirement scikit-learn<=0.20.3,>=0.19.0, but you'll have scikit-learn 0.22.1 which is incompatible.

Comment: In the comment error says that "azureml-train-automl 1.0.72 has requirement onnxmltools==1.4.1", which means that you have the azureml-train-automl of version 1.0.72 which supports the old version of onnxmltools,that is 1.4.1. You now have the latest version of onnxmltools which is 1.6.0. https://pypi.org/project/onnxmltools/ . Please uninstall and then reinstall onnxmltools with version 1.4.1.   https://pypi.org/project/onnxmltools/#history . This link have the earlier versions which is downloadable.

Comment: I fixed it. Not more any error message. And still not get the updated sklearn. Requirement already up-to-date: scikit-learn in /home/nbuser/anaconda3_501/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.22.1)...sklearn.__version__ always the same 0.20.3

Comment: Now sklearn can be updated using the below command:             pip install --user --upgrade scikit-learn==0.22.1

Comment: It worked on Anaconda Jupyter notebook. Not in Azure notebooks. Also you can google "Need to update scikit learn packages in Azure ML studio"

Comment: This would have worked on Azure notebooks as well because Azure is just a service to run jupyter notebooks

Answer (score 0):

https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/package-installation

The

```
!pip !pip install scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

option did not work, even if it showed

```
Successfully installed joblib-0.14.1 scikit-learn-0.22.1
```

Instead,

```
!conda install scikit-learn==0.22.1  -y
```

was succesful, and I executed the code correctly. It took some minutes.

As stated, your packages will **only** be available for the lifetime of your notebook server and **only** in the current project.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Answer (score -1):

Stuff to pay attention to:

- Kernel needs to be restarted if you already imported sklearn (even with the `%autoreload 2` magic).
- If you changed your kernel from the default (eg from *Python 3.6 - AzureML* to *3.8*), your PATH may not have followed (see `!which pip`) and you may be installing in the wrong kernel. To install in 3.8 I had to run:

```sh
! /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/bin/pip install --user -U scikit-learn
```

Same trick for conda `/anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/bin/conda install -y scikit-learn==0.24.2`.
I don't believe conda will have any advantage in this case, except as an excuse for taking a coffee during its crawling dependency resolution.

Upgrading from 0.22 to 0.24.2 in *Python 3.8 - Azure ML* still yields some error messages, but you can safely ignore them if you're not using these packages (and maybe even if you are)

> ERROR: raiwidgets 0.4.0 has requirement ipython==7.16.1, but you'll have ipython 7.18.1 which is incompatible.
> ERROR: raiwidgets 0.4.0 has requirement jinja2==2.11.1, but you'll have jinja2 2.11.2 which is incompatible.